# https not showing wsdl page (WCF)

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wsdl

I have followed the MSDN site for creating a https site for a WCF (4.5, using simplified configuration) web service
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556232(v=vs.110).aspx

When I navigate to my website of `http` or `https`. It is showing me the landing page fine (the one that says 'you have created a service' and points you to the wsdl, etc), so I know my certificates are ok.

However, the link displayed in the web service landing page to find the wsdl is showing as `http://` and not `https://` and when I try and navigate to https://example.com?singleWsdl

all I get is the same welcome page and not the wsdl.

All is fine with `http`.

Here is the entries I changed to support `https`. Is there anything else I need to do? I made no code changes.

```xml
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="HttpBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
   maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
   maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" 
      maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
      maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
      maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" 
    />
  </binding>

 <binding name="HttpsBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
    maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
    <security mode="Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
    </security>
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" 
       maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
       maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
       maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" 
    />
 </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>

<protocolMapping>
  <add scheme="http" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="HttpBinding" />
   <add scheme="https" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="HttpsBinding" />
 </protocolMapping>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about activating `ServiceMetadata` with this parameter ?

```
   <serviceBehaviors>
    ...
    <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
    ...        
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

Source : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731317(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1

Check out the end of their exemple (I cannot seems to put it as a quote)

Comment: Hello, this is 4.5, you don't need service entry (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358768(v=vs.110).aspx). I actually got sent a web.config from a colleague who did exactly the same thing and his worked...

Comment: You're right. Still there is no trace about this httpsGetEnabled in your config file.

Comment: You're right, I already have the behaviors in but only for httpGetEnabled, so I added httpsGetEnabled="true" and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't manage to bold the "s" in the config snippet to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

What do your endpoints look like?  I believe for https, you would need an mexHttpsBinding endpoint.  Something like:

`<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" name="MexHttpsBindingEndpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />`

Comment: Hello, this is 4.5, you don't need service entry (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358768(v=vs.110).aspx). I actually got sent a web.config from a colleague who did exactly the same thing and his worked...